# How to display 0 as duration ( format 00:00:00) in Telerik Reporting?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a Telerik report and I'm working on Telerik Report designer , I'm trying to convert 0 to format `HH:mm:ss` , I'm trying this defined function `Format(format,args)` like this:

```
= IsNull(Fields.duration,format("HH:mm:ss",0))
```

but I got always `0` and the result that I would like to get :

```
00:00:00
```

[image]

How can I dot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem from SQL Server Side ( modify the stored procedure ) .

**Old query :**

```
select distinct 0 as duration
```

***Output of this query:***

```
Duration
  NULL
```

**New query:**

```
select distinct cast(MSDB.DBO.AGENT_DATETIME(20210101,0) as time)  as duration
```

***Output of this query:***

```
   Duration
00:00:00.0000000
```

In Telerik reporting, the expression will be :

```
= Fields.duration
```

*Reference:*    https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/13/sql-server-interesting-function-agent_datetime/